# Kickstarter-like solution for OpenBSD?

Tags: system-installation, openbsd

Are there any solutions for OpenBSD to just:

Insert the custom installer CD, press enter (like: "are you sure?" - message), then the installer automatically partitions the disk/installs OpenBSD, and then customize it a little (ex.: install a few apps from ports)?

This can be done using Kickstarter for RHEL. **But can it be done for OpenBSD?** I googled for it and didn't found any good answer yet (only that needs bigger programming skills..).

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~brendan/howtos/openbsd_install/. Also there are others on this site: http://blog.boreas.ro/2007/11/unix-deployment-tools-jumpstart.html, in the BSD section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An OpenBSD install does most of that currently, but you just have to press "enter" a lot.  As for doing the pkg_installs and other customizations, there is (and has been for a long time) a mechanism to do that, although it's harder to track down the documentation if you don't know what you are looking for.  The installer will pull a sitexx.tgz or sitexx-hostname.tgz install set if it is on your installer source.

The FAQ has a lot of details here:
http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#site

The one other big tip I'll give you that is also mentioned there is the rc.firsttime(8) script mechanism.  If you drop a file at /etc/rc.firsttime, those commands will be run at the next boot and then the file is deleted.  If doing so in the installer, *append* to that file, since the installer uses it to.

I saw some rumblings on the mailing lists that a developer is working on an even more automated mechanism for the installer too...

UPDATE 2014-05-01 - [`autoinstall(8)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=autoinstall&sektion=8) Automatic Install ability included in 5.5: http://www.openbsd.org/55.html

Answer (score 1):

[`autoinstall(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/autoinstall) is your tool to do this task since OpenBSD 5.5. Using `dhcp+pxe` and a http server you are good enough to deploy an automated install infrastructure. This topic is well explained on [this bsdnow.tv](https://www.bsdnow.tv/tutorials/autoinstall) how-to, but I will make some comments on this how-to:

Create a dhcp pxe entry. The example below, will search for the `auto_install` file instead of `pxeboot`

```
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    filename "auto_install";
    next-server 192.168.1.1;
    range 192.168.1.8 192.168.1.254;
[..other stuff..]
}
```

Using a `tftp` server, host the needed files to boot using pxe. You will also need to enable pxe-boot at the client site on its bios:

```
# ls -l /tftp

total 12896
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        7 Feb 22 21:37 auto_install -> pxeboot
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  6501415 Feb 22 12:49 bsd
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    80524 Feb 22 12:50 pxeboot
```

Host all the installation packages inside your `htdocs` root directory, and configure your [`httpd.conf`](https://man.openbsd.org/httpd.conf.5) accordingly :

```
# ls /var/www/htdocs/pub/OpenBSD/5.5/i386/

SHA256       bsd          comp55.tgz   index.txt    xetc55.tgz   xshare55.tgz
SHA256.sig   bsd.mp       etc55.tgz    man55.tgz    xfont55.tgz
base55.tgz   bsd.rd       game55.tgz   xbase55.tgz  xserv55.tgz
```

Inside your `httpd` root directory, create an `install.conf` file with all the answers to the questions asked by the installer.

```
# cat /var/www/htdocs/install.conf

System hostname = bsdnow.tv
Password for root = ThePlaceToBe...SD
Network interfaces = em0
IPv4 address for em0 = dhcp
Setup a user = puffy
Password for user = whywasibornasafish
What timezone are you in = US/Eastern
Location of sets = http
Server = 192.168.1.1
```

Note that you could be also using `nginx` here. The important thing here is that it needs to be placed at the server root with the `install.conf` name. Also, there is no comprehensive list of the parameters that can be used at `autoinstall` so, do your search to find good examples like [here](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=8825). Quoting `autoinstall` manpages:

> The response file is a line-oriented ASCII text file. The format of
>   each line is:
>
> ```
> question = answer
> ```
>
> question is an installer question (not including the question mark) or
>   a non-ambiguous part of it, consisting of whitespace separated words.
>   answer is the answer to the question. Passwords may be in plaintext,
>   encrypted with encrypt(1), or set to ‘*************’ (13 '*'s) to
>   disable password logins, only permitting alternative access methods
>   (for example, ssh(1) keys).

You can also use `MAC_address-install.conf` or `hostname-install.conf`(if hostname is defined at `dhcpd.conf`) to create an install routine to just one host.

Just boot up the machine, and wait for the installation job to finish.

Also, sky is the limit here. Take a look at this [Complicated Example](https://slides.cobug.org/view/OpenBSD_Autoinstall#/21) from [CoBUG](https://cobug.org/) that will create a vm dinamically, feed database and httpd files to configure it and start the installation. All with just one command ;)